# Is hypnotic susceptibility associated with responsiveness to rapid vs. standard hypnosis induction?

Tags: hypnosis

I have been learning about hypnosis, inductions etc. and I have heard how there is a spectrum of how able people are to be hypnotised. There are those who will go into trance at the drop of a hat, and others who are near-impossible to induce a trance state on.

My question is, is there a correlation between where one is on this spectrum, and the success rates of rapid compared to standard hypnosis?

Any extra info would be nice. Thanks!

Comment: Check out research on [absorption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorption_(psychology)), a relevant personality trait.

Answer (score 1):

I am studying hypnotherapy myself and from what I am led to believe, there is no "spectrum of how able people are to be hypnotised".  Everyone who wants to be hypnotised can be.  How quickly they are hypnotised depends on the experience of the hypnotherapist and their methods used.

Take a look at Elman and Ericksonian Inductions in Google.  There are good videos on YouTube showing you the different methods.  Milton H. Erickson developed a permissive style of induction which is considered slower than Dave Elman's authoritarian style.  The thing you would need to consider is what style is suited to your client.  You would need to develop your own induction routine based on these 2 styles and you may then have to tailor the induction to their modality (Kinaesthetic, Visual, Auditory, Olfactory, or Gustatory).

Hope this helps

Comment: Do you know if there is any peer-reviewed research looking at this issue?